# How to use the carousel in bootstrap with data rendered from node js?

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, bootstrap-5

What I want to do is create a carousel that shows my 5 different pieces of information and that information is from a separate app.js. I have tried to use a for each loop but as soon as I tried to create by second bootstrap carousel container I realized it was not working.

code:

```
    <div class="carousel-item active">  
        <div class="container">
    
               <% burgers.forEach(function(burger) { %>
            
              <img id="brg-image" src= "<%= burger.image %> ">
               <br>
              <strong><h2 id="brg-title"><%= burger.name %></h2></strong>
              <div id="description"><h6><%= burger.description %></h6></div>
          
            
          <% }); %>
            
            
            
            
      </div>
   </div>
       
        
     </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must check whether both of bootstrap.min.js and bootstrap.min.css file are imported.
There is nothing to bother you.

Comment: yep they are both imported, is it right to put a loop in there though cause im not sure how to create a second or third carousel item